# Have journal names appear in short form in text and long in the bibliography with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing

I have a bibliography file which contains definitions in the journal name field, for example `\pra`, and I define this in my file as `\def \pra {Phys. Rev. A}`, which is what I want for my bibliography.

Now I would also like to be able to have a command like `\citearticleshort` or something, which would insert a shorthand for the journal name, for example PRA in this case, plus volume number and possibly page.

How can I get `\pra` to expand to Phys. Rev. A in one case and PRA in another case? I saw there is something like mapping in biblatex, but I couldn't figure out how to use it to solve my problem.

Comment: Mapping probably won't help you (as mapping changes a field permanently for `biblatex`), but `biblatex` provides `\ifcitation` and `\ifbibliography` that are true only if we are currently in a citation or in the bibliography, respectively. So you might do `\newcommand*{\pra}{\ifcitation{PRA}{Phys. Rev. A}}`. Of course you also might use a completely custom toggle here, but then you need to be more specific as to when what is to appear. (Not tested for lack of an MWE.)

Comment: that does exactly what I want! thanks a lot. If you convert your comment into an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`biblatex` has the `\ifcitation` and `\ifbibliography` tests to check whether we are in a citation or the bibliography, respectively.

In your case, we might define `\pra` as

```
\newcommand*{\pra}{%
  \ifcitation
    {PRA}
    {Phys. Rev. A}}
```

such that `\pra` expands to "PRA" in a citation and to "Phys. Rev. A" everywhere else (especially in the bibliography).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{pra,
  author = {Anne Uthor},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {\pra},
  year = {2008},
  volume = {15},
  number = {7},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcommand*{\pra}{\ifcitation{PRA}{Phys. Rev. A}}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{pra}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]